# XML iterating over a root to print elements by their tags

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, elementtree

I have a XML file like this:

[image]

and I want to iterate through it to print out the temperature every time the tag is `<temperature>`.

Is there any functions built into xml.etree.ElementTree or lxml or other libraries I can use to do this?

Here's my current effort but that just prints all of the elements

[image]

Comment: Could you share a the code and the examples as text and not images? That will allow us to reproduce the issue and help you solve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best ways to process XML is with XPath. [lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) has better support as [ElementTree's XPath support is limited](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). But either one would work in your example.

Here's an example using lxml:

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("dub_airport.xml")

for temp in tree.xpath(".//temperature"):
    print(f"The temperature value is \"{temp.text}\".")
```

If you really need to iterate (like if your XML is very large and you have memory issues), you can use something like [`iter()`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#tree-iteration)  or [`iterparse()`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#event-driven-parsing).

Here's an example using iterparse() in lxml:

```py
from lxml import etree

for event, elem in etree.iterparse("dub_airport.xml", tag="temperature", events=("start",)):
    print(f"The temperature value is \"{elem.text}\".")
    elem.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate until a specific tag name you should loop in root and use `.tag` instance to compare if it is equal to `'temperature'` in this case, for a simple case I have display some values by using `tag`, `attrib` and `text` objects.

```
>>> for child in root:
...     for child_tag in child:
...         if (child_tag.tag == 'temperature'):
...             print(child_tag.tag, child_tag.attrib, child_tag.text)
...
```

output:

```
temperature {} 11
temperature {} 11
temperature {} 11
```